# Shared Object Undefined Symbol Tinxml Tinystr

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I am working with Swig (C++ and Python) and am creating a shared library out of my Swig C++ wrappers and my modules. I use tinyxml.h and tinystr.h. When I compiled everything into a shared library I originally received this error:

```
ImportError: ./_e2ParserSwig.so: undefined symbol: _ZN11TiXmlString8nullrep_E
```

This wasn't a problem I just forgot to include the tinyxml.o and tinystr.o into my shared library. Also the above issue is all over the web from people experiencing the same thing.

On a not so fortunate scheme of events, this didn't get rid of my undefined symbols. I now get this as an unknown symbol:

```
ImportError: ./_e2ParserSwig.so: undefined symbol: _ZN12TiXmlUnknown5ParseEPKcP16TiXmlParsingData13TiXmlEncoding
```

This undefined symbol seems to be unique, it is definetly apart of the tinyxml/tinystr libraries, but is seamlessly non existent as far as the web.